# Write a snippet that removes the initial variable at the end, leaving only the modified ones

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

Let's say I have an UltiSnips snippet that shall replace all special characters with an underscore.

I have this:

```
snippet us "replace specials with underscores" w
${1:${VISUAL}}
`!p
import re
snip.rv = re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "_", t[1])
`
endsnippet
```

Now something like `Hello world!` becomes:

```
Hello world!
Hello_World_
```

However, at the end, I would like to keep only the second line and discard what I typed initially. Is that possible? Maybe using `post_expand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to write any python code. Your snippet is as simple as the following:

```
snippet us "replace specials with underscores" w
${1:${VISUAL/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/_/g}}
endsnippet
```

In a more general manner we are able to retrieve the text that was selected in visual mode through `snip.v.text` property. so just change `t[1]` to that and also remove `${1:${VISUAL}}`:

```
snippet us "replace specials with underscores" w
`!p
import re
snip.rv = re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "_", snip.v.text)
`
endsnippet
```

Comment: Okay, okay. Thank you. However, my problem was a simplified one which you now solved, but for my real one, I need python. Do you know how to solve that as well?